# Keeping textarea data in php

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

i want to keep a textarea data in php, so when i refresh the page the text is still there. So I tried this, but everytime i refresh the page the text disappears. If someone can help me , i'd be thankful.

PHP code:

```
<?php 
$comments = "";
$comments= $_POST['comments'];
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<textarea name="comments" value="<?php echo $comments ?>" cols="30" rows="3" class="w3-input w3-round-large" placeholder="add some infos about yourself !!"></textarea><br>
```

Comment: A [<textarea>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) doesn't use the `value` attribute. Place content between the opening and closing tag

Comment: yes , i forgot to check before posting it. Sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The textarea doesn't have a value attribute, so if you want to put a value in there you need to do it in middle of the  tags:

```
<textarea name="comments" cols="30" rows="3" class="w3-input w3-round-large" placeholder="add some infos about yourself !!"><?php echo $comments ?></textarea>
```